# SelectPDF Erro C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp

Estou usando o ou SelectPDF para converter uma string HTML em pdf local funciona perfeitamente, mas emprodução mostra o seguinte erro.

[image: 1]

Estou está usando um servidor IIS.
Todos os .ddl's de produção estão no servidore, já tentei alterar o web.config para aumentar o tamanho dos arquivos suportados (esse .pdf tem apenas uma página imagino que não haja problema aí).

Answer (score 1):

Era a largura da Imagem, não sei pq mas em produção ela nn tava conseguindo converter o html com a imagem com a largura de 1700px de largura ,é isso fé.